# REACT getCiphers is not a function at ./node_modules/ssh2-sftp-client/node_modules/ssh2/lib/protocol/keyParser.js

Tags: reactjs, sftp, ssh2-sftp-client

Sto provando ad usare la libreria 'ssh2-sftp-client' ma nel momento in cui faccio la dichiarazione
let Client = require('ssh2-sftp-client')
va in errore, qualcuno mi può aiutare?
Grazie

getCiphers is not a function  at ./node_modules/ssh2-sftp-client/node_modules/ssh2/lib/protocol/keyParser.js

Comment: So is English-only site.